# Conditional text based on product category in WooCommerce customer completed order email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, email-notifications

I'm trying to echo some text in the order completed email generated by WooCommerce according to a set of conditions based on the product category in the order table.

I have 4 product categories (cat-one, cat-two, cat-three, cat-four).

One category has variable products (just in case it matters although I was testing on orders without it)

The conditions I'd like to have are:

1. Only for customer order completed email
2. IF the order has only products in cat-one THEN use "SOME TEXT"
3. IF the order has products in cat-one AND products from any other categories THEN use "SOME OTHER TEXT"
4. IF the order has products from ALL categories except cat-one THEN use "ANOTHER TEXT"

What I have tried so far:

```php
function add_instructions_to_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
$cat_one = false;
$cat_two = false;
$cat_three = false;
$cat_four = false;

$items = $order->get_items(); 
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {      
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();  
        //CHECK WHICH CATEGORIES ARE IN THE ORDER
       
        if ( has_term( 'cat_one', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $cat_one=true;
            
        }
        if ( has_term( 'cat_two', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $cat_two=true;
            
        }
        if ( has_term( 'cat_three', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $cat_three=true;
            
        }
        if ( has_term( 'cat_four', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $cat_four=true;
            
        }


if ( $email->id == 'customer_completed_order') {
    // 1. ONLY CAT-ONE
        if ( $cat_one)  {
            echo "SOME TEXT";
        }
        
    // 2. CAT-ONE and any other Category   
        elseif ( $cat_one && $cat_two || $cat_three || $cat_four) {
            if($order->has_shipping_method('local_pickup')) {
                echo "SOME TEXT";
            } else {
                echo "SOME OTHER TEXT";
            }

        }
    // 3. THERE IS NO CAT-ONE IN THE ORDER
        elseif ( !$cat_one && $cat_two || $cat_three || $cat_four ) {
            if ($order->has_shipping_method('local_pickup')) {
                echo "SOME TEXT";
               
            } else {
                echo "SOME OTHER TEXT";
            }
    }

  }
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'add_instructions_to_email', 20, 4 );
```

---

It's not working as expected. I also tried using `elseif` statements in the `foreach` and conditionals directly in the `has_term` statement. No success.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has some minor errors, following code/answer contains:

1. Only for customer order completed email
2. IF the order has only products in cat-one THEN use "SOME TEXT"
3. IF the order has products in cat-one AND products from any other categories THEN use "SOME OTHER TEXT"
4. IF the order has products from ALL categories except cat-one THEN use "ANOTHER TEXT"

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_email_before_order_table( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {   
    // Only for order completed email 
    if ( $email->id == 'customer_completed_order' ) {
        // Booleans
        $cat_one = false;
        $cat_two = false;
        $cat_three = false;
        $cat_four = false;
        
        // Output
        $output = '';
        
        // Loop through order items
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            // Product ID
            $product_id = $item->get_variation_id() > 0 ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();

            // Has term (product category)
            if ( has_term( 'cat-one', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
                $cat_one = true;
            }
            
            if ( has_term( 'cat-two', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
                $cat_two = true;
            }
            
            if ( has_term( 'cat-three', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
                $cat_three = true;
            }
            
            if ( has_term( 'cat-four', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
                $cat_four = true;
            }
        }
        
        // 1. ONLY CAT-ONE
        if ( $cat_one ) {
            $output = "SOME TEXT";
            
            // 2. CAT-ONE and any other Category
            if ( $cat_two || $cat_three || $cat_four ) {
                $output = "SOME OTHER TEXT";
            }
        } else {
            // 3. ALL CATEGORIES EXCEPT CAT-ONE
            if ( $cat_two && $cat_three && $cat_four ) {
                $output = "ANOTHER TEXT";
            }           
        }
        
        // Output
        echo $output;
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'action_woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Thank you very much @7uc1f3r. I had to make a little change for condition two but your answer was super helpful. All works as expected now.